# Automount NTFS drives before startup applications

Tags: 13.04, mount, ntfs, automount

Before I start, I just what to point out that I know how to automount an NTFS drive. 
My problem is that my dropbox folder is on one of the ntfs drivers that I automounted... When ubuntu starts up, it loads the dropbox application before it mounts the ntfs drive which results in an error "Dropbox folder not found"!

**So how can I automount the parition before all startup applications ?** (I am using Ubuntu 13.04)

PS. I am not planning on moving my dropbox folder to my user folder, I would like to leave it on the ntfs partition ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it without mounting your NTFS drive earlier, just starting Dropbox later.

```
#!/bin/bash
#insert seconds to wait before dropbox start
wait 15
dropbox
```

And add that script to your Startup Applications.

Allthough I am not sure why you have that issue, I myself never had that issue and I always had the Dropbox Directory on an NTFS drive.